# Gridview Clickable Rows for Message Inbox

Tags: asp.net, gridview, messaging, clickable

I know there's a few other questions like this but I couldn't figure it out based on their answers.

I'm building a messaging inbox page using gridview. Currently, the gridview shows a user their messages with the column headers being: Sent from, Subject, and Date. I am hoping to make the rows clickable (and highlighted when clicked) and the message to appear in a text box next to the gridview box. I want the row clickable, but not have that "Select" button on the side of each row.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure if I need to change the properties of my gridview box or make a completely new method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you add a button command on your GridView as:

```
<asp:ButtonField Text="View" CommandName="ViewMe" ButtonType="Button" />
```

then you add the `OnRowCommand="RowCommand"` property on `GridView` and on code behind the function:

```
protected void RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // if the ViewMe command is fired
    if (e.CommandName == "ViewMe")
    {
        // go to find the index on the grid view
        int iTheIndexNow;
        if (int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out iTheIndexNow))
        {
            // Set and highlight the selected
            gvGridViewID.SelectedIndex = iTheIndexNow;

            // get the table data id
            if (gvGridViewID.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                // now load the text where gvGridViewID.SelectedValue is 
                // the line id. This function load the text 
                //   into a TextBox or other control
                LoadText(gvGridViewID.SelectedValue.ToString());
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

On this function you set the selected row and you get the SelectedValue that you set on `DataKeyNames`, usually the ID from your table. Having this id you can show the extra text of your message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was wondering, what is gvGridViewID in your behind code? Is that just the ID name for the gridview box? Finally, I assumed there would need to be a query to get the body of the message from the database. Is that not necessary in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin The `gvGridViewID` is the ID (name) of the GridView.

Comment: @Kevin Yes you need to query to get the message body - why to keep it on page, I think is too much to keep 20 message body on the page just to select then one to show it.

Comment: Where does the query code go? And my thought in this page was to imitate sort of the Outlook email messaging system. When you click any of the messages, the text box changes to show the body of that 1 message. That way you keep everything on the same page. I need to experiment around and see though, may be easier to just load a new page with the body. I think this is also similar to Ebay's messaging system, the message appears below and keeps you on the same page.